# Formatar valor como moeda

Tags: php

Preciso em `PHP` formatar o valor `1.174.36` em `1174.36`

Preciso remover todos os pontos anteriores do centavo.
 
Estou quebrando a cabeça aqui mas não consigo achar a solução.

todas as soluções que consigo achar é o inverso do que estou precisando exemplo se for 100.100.000.10 preciso que fique em 100100000.10

Se poderem me ajudar fico muito grato

Comment: todos os pontos anteriores do centavo preciso remover

Comment: caso alguem um dia tenha o mesmo problema:

$valor_pedido_expode = explode('.', $valor_pedido);
  $valor_pedido_expode2 = explode('.', $valor_pedido);
  end($valor_pedido_expode);
  key($valor_pedido_expode);
  $valor__pedido_final = '';
  foreach ($valor_pedido_expode2 as $key => $valor_de_cada) {
   if($key == key($valor_pedido_expode)){
    $valor__pedido_final .= '.'.$valor_de_cada;
   }else{
    $valor__pedido_final .= $valor_de_cada;
   }
  }